# Compare dynamic arrays of string angular 6

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have two arrays of strings. One of those will be a dynamic list of checkboxes. I want to check if the item exists in the other array. How can I do it dynamically using angular 6?

This is the current situation of the list of checkboxes...
The checked need to be dynamic...

```
<div *ngFor="let p of people">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin secondary-text"
        [checked]="false" >p</mat-checkbox>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the **other array**? How does the structure of the `p` looks like?

Comment: @Senal The 'p' looks like 

Array(34)
0: "ITEM_1"
1: "ITEM_2"
2: "ITEM_3"
3: "ITEM_4"
...

And the other array has the same structure

Comment: why not to have one array (called people) where object is a  person like this: [ { name: "whatevername", checked: false }, ... ]. If you do have already the arrays and you can not changed them please share as part of the question

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you want to check the items which are also existing inside the `otherArray`. This is assuming that these arrays are string arrays as you mentioned.

```
// In the template
<div *ngFor="let p of people">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin secondary-text"
    [checked]="isInOtherArray(p)" >p</mat-checkbox>
</div>

// In the component method
public isInOtherArray(person) {

   return this.otherArray.indexOf(person) > -1;
}
```

Or you could directly use it on your template

```
<div *ngFor="let p of people">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin secondary-text"
    [checked]="otherArray.indexOf(p) > -1" >p</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```